# Mysql limit 2 rows per date per user

Tags: mysql, mysql-variables

Okay so lets say I have a basic table

**thing**

```
id
user_id
created_at
```

And some data

```
id  user_id  created_at
1     1      2016-09-06
2     1      2016-09-06 
3     1      2016-09-06 
4     1      2016-09-07 
5     1      2016-09-08 
6     1      2016-09-08 
7     1      2016-09-08
```

What I want to achive is selecting **max two rows per USER per DATE of created_at**. I'm only displaying data from one user, but I hope you get the point.

So the results of the select should be

```
id  user_id  created_at
1     1      2016-09-06 
2     1      2016-09-06 
4     1      2016-09-07 
5     1      2016-09-08 
6     1      2016-09-08
```

I know I somehow have to use the **LIMIT** keyword, but I'm not so sure how. I'm also pretty sure I have to use a subquery and group by the date.

I hope you understand the problem and please do ask some questions if there's something difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use variables:

```
SELECT id, user_id, created_at
FROM (
  SELECT id, user_id, created_at,
         @rn := IF(@dt = created_at, @rn + 1,
                   IF(@dt := created_at, 1, 1)) AS rn
  FROM mytable
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @dt := '1900-01-01') AS var
  ORDER BY created_at) AS t
WHERE t.rn <= 2
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/10e1f/2)